# Cannot check out maven projects in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am trying to check out a maven projects in Netbeans.  However, I am failing.  The error message I get whenever I try to check something out is:

Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you don't have `svn` in your `PATH`.

If you're running Windows, try `echo %PATH%` in command line and check if svn is available in the folders that are in your path.

If you're using Linux, try `which svn`. If nothing is returned, `svn` is not installed.

For Windows, I'm using [silksvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) command line client.

Comment: That is it.  I did not believe anything was wrong with my subversion configuration because subversion worked through Netbeans.  However, no command line svn was installed on my machine.

Comment: subversion working through netbeans might be irrelevant, since it's porbably using an embedded java impl, while the maven scm plugin uses just the svn found on path. http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html